# Ocean Protocol: Decentralized Big Data Sharing and Artificial Intelligence

Tags: bigdata, artificial-intelligence, immutability, blockchain, decentralized-applications

[Ocean Protocol](https://oceanprotocol.com/tech-whitepaper.pdf) claims that it created a "decentralized data marketplace" using decentralization of data sharing by blockchain. They say that their platform can be used in Artificial Intelligence. However, the amount of data employed in Artificial Intelligence is hugely big in size. (Please have a look [here](https://bitcoinexchangeguide.com/ocean-protocol/), where it introduces this protocol.)

One of the serious questions is that where does data get stored, especially, when the sizes of data are huge? The Ocean protocol white paper answers this question as follows:

> Ocean itself does not store the data. Instead, it links to data that
>   is stored, and provides mechanisms for access control. The most
>   sensitive data (e.g. medical data) should be behind firewalls,
>   on-premise. Via its services framework, Ocean can bring the compute to
>   the data, using on-premise compute. Other data may be on a centralized
>   cloud (e.g. [Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/s3/)) or decentralized cloud (e.g. [Filecoin](https://filecoin.io/filecoin.pdf)). In both cases it should be encrypted. This means that
>   the Ocean blockchain does not store data itself. This also means that
>   we **can remove** the data, if it’s not on a **decentralized** and **immutable**
>   substrate.

So, Does not it mean that Ocean blockchain cannot provide **immutability** of shared data?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. Ocean itself does not store the data, so it has no control over whether the data is stored immutably (or not).